# The header does not appear for the ones who install ipa

Tags: objective-c, ios

I set the header in my CustomTabBarViewController

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, self.bounds , [UIImage imageNamed:@"capiton_haut.png"].CGImage);

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]))
    {
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(155, 5, 170, 37), [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_pages.png"].CGImage);
    }
    else {
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(75, 5, 170, 37), [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_pages.png"].CGImage);
    }
}
@end

@implementation CustomTabBarViewController.....
```

When I tested I see the header. After I d arhive and send ipa to testers they don t have bugs but they cannot see header . Is black .

Thanks, 
Raluca

Comment: wild guess: it should be `capTIon_haut`, not `capITon_haut`. Or that image is not in the project.

Comment: devices are case-sensitive unlike simulator. check your image name if it has capital.

Comment: it does not have . it is correctly spelled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the image inside the IPA? Seems like you forgot it or the name is different from "capiton_haut.png".

**EDIT:**

Instead of using category create a UINavigationBar subclass to override the `drawRect:` method. This should solve your problem, and work on iOS 5.

Comment: how I verify this ? if it is inside ipa ? Why should not be ? n my phone it looks ok.

Comment: I found the images in archive . I don t understand ....it may be because of tester phone?

Comment: When I am looking at images in arhive I see them but if I open them they seem empty ...

Comment: That's because Xcode "compress" your images when the app is built. To save space.

Comment: What else should I try to do ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8590/discussion-between-fbernardo-and-raluca-gurau)

Comment: Are you using categories again to that buttons?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785488/buttons-from-navigation-bar-don-t-appear-since-i-create-customnavigationbar

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of problems before, check that "capiton_haut.png" is correctly spelled, cause the simulator is not case sensitive but the device could be!