# Buttons from navigation bar don t appear since I create CustomNavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have created a custom navigation Bar

```
#import "UICustomNavigationBar.h"


@implementation UICustomNavigationBar 
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextDrawImage(context, self.bounds , [UIImage    imageNamed:@"capitonhaut.png"].CGImage);

if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]))
{
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(155, 5, 170, 37), [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_BEST.png"].CGImage);
}
else {
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(75, 5, 170, 37), [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_BEST.png"].CGImage);
}
}

@end
```

Than in my AppDelegate I have

```
 UICustomNavigationBar *navBar = [[UICustomNavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window.bounds.size.width,50)];

[self.window sendSubviewToBack:self.tabBar.view];
[self.window addSubview:navBar];

[navBar release];
```

I try to add buttons in some pages like this

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]   initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok",@"Ok") style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(onSortButtonTap:)]];
```

When I din not have custom navigation bar this code worked.

Thanks

Raluca

Comment: Is your custom nav bar part of a `UINavigationController`? Is it a proper subclass of `UINavigationBar`?

Answer (score 1):

You must have a navigationItem to set a right bar button, in my test (that works) I have:

```
    UICustomNavigationBar *navBar =[[UICustomNavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
    [self.view addSubview:navBar];           
    [navBar pushNavigationItem:[[[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil] autorelease] animated:NO];
    navBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]   initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok",@"Ok") style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(onSortButtonTap:)] autorelease];

    [navBar release];
```

Comment: The buttons are shown..just that I have 2 headers now , one empty and one with buttons . I understand why ..I draw new one in this class...Some buttons should appear just in some pages . So I set the uicustomnav bar in My app delegate. Can I access it from other pages and add on it some buttons? Thanks

Comment: Read the overview part in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html it really helped me to understand UINavigationController and UINavigationBar.

Comment: I use UiNavigationController for footbar, and it works properly , but I don t understand how I can set the app navigation bar = mycustom navigation bar and how I can to add from other Controllers button to this one. If I addSubview It will draw 2

Comment: Hmm, I can't fully understand your problem. Can we chat latter?

Comment: I don t get it ...I don t understand how to do relationship with MyCstomTabViewController. I see that property navigation bar is read only so..i can not practicaly set.

Comment: Tab? What tab view controller?

Comment: I have a custom tab view controller that extends UiViewController <Clllocationmangerdelegate> .This contains the footbar .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9200/discussion-between-fbernardo-and-raluca-gurau)